# Replacing SimpleXMLObject objects by strings in array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have an array with information that I get from the Amazon API and parsed it using SimpleXML. This gives me an array that looks like this :

```
[
    [
        0 => SimpleXMLElement Object (0 => B00TU53O8Q)
    ], [
        0 => SimpleXMLElement Object (0 => B00TU53O8Q),
        1 => SimpleXMLElement Object (0 => B015K13HWQ)
    ], [
        0 => SimpleXMLElement Object (0 => B00TU53O8Q) 
    ], [
       ...
    ]
]
```

Now, I want to convert this array to a more simplified format that no longer has any SimpleXML objects in them anymore.

Basically, I just want an array with only the strings they represent :

```
[
    0 => B00TU53O8Q,
    1 => B015K13HWQ,
    2 => B00TU53O8Q,
    1 => B00TU53O8Q
       ...
]
```

I then want to split that array into a 2-dimentional array, that looks something like this :

```
[
    0 => [
        0 => B00TU53O8Q
        1 => B00TU53O8Q
        2 => B015K13HWQ
        3 => B00TU53O8Q
        4 => B00TU53O8Q
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => B015K13HWQ
       ...
    ]
    ...
]
```

I don't know how to do this. Can you please help me?!

Comment: The input is the information that i get from the amazon API. I will update the code now.

Comment: updated the code. Thanks

Comment: Added My input and desired response. Thank you.

Comment: updated the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to process your input:

```
function translate($data, &$result) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach($data as $element) {
            translate($element, $result);
        }
    } else {
        $result[] = (string) $data; 
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
// some test data:
$data = array(
    array(
        new SimpleXMLElement("<test>B00TU53O8Q</test>")
    ),
    array(
        new SimpleXMLElement("<test>B00TU53O8Q</test>"),
        new SimpleXMLElement("<test>B015K13HWQ</test>")
    ),
    array(
        new SimpleXMLElement("<test>B00TU53O8Q</test>")
    ),
    array(
        new SimpleXMLElement("<test>B00TU53O8Q</test>"),
        new SimpleXMLElement("<test>B015K13HWQ</test>")
    )
);

$result = array();
translate($data, $result);
```

If you want to break up the *$result* array in chunks of 5, then proceed like this:

```
$chunks = array();
while (count($result)) {
    $chuncks[] = array_slice($result, 0, 5);
    $result = array_slice($result, 5);
}

print_r ($chuncks);
```

Ouput, based on test data, gives 2 chunks:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => B00TU53O8Q
            [1] => B00TU53O8Q
            [2] => B015K13HWQ
            [3] => B00TU53O8Q
            [4] => B00TU53O8Q
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B015K13HWQ
        )

)
```

Comment: I will try it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

right off the bat I think your if statement is wrong. Should be a double == if you are making a comparison. Essentially you are setting $asinValue equal to 'Asin Not Found' and it will evaluate true. It does not seem like you will ever get to the else portion of your code.

Comment: Take a look at the question again. I changed it to find something that would fit my needs better. Thank you for your quick response.